# Numpy Indexing without Intermediates

Tags: python, numpy, indexing

Does the following code first create an intermediate (for holding `rep[data]`) and then copying the intermediate to the existing `out` array?

If that is the case, how to do this without creating the intermediate?

Program:

```
import numpy as np

data = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3])    
out = np.empty(data.shape)  # existing array
rep = np.array([1,3,5,7])
out[:] = rep[data]  # intermediate?

print(out)
```

Result:

```
[ 1.  3.  1.  3.  3.  5.  3.  7.]
```

Thanks.

Comment: Yes, it does. Why even create a `np.empty` array? Just do `out = rep[data]`

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ If it creates an intermediate array and the program do this for many times, then how bad is the overhead for recreating the intermediates?

Comment: Not much, depending on how large your arrays are. You can't really avoid it though.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Does the following code first create an intermediate (for holding rep[data]) and then copying the intermediate to the existing out array?

Yes. Get used to scratch arrays; NumPy makes a lot of them, and they're not all avoidable.

> If that is the case, how to do this without creating the intermediate?

The simple way is

```
data = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3])    
rep = np.array([1,3,5,7])
out = rep[data]
```

but if you have an existing array and you really need to populate *that array* with the results, you can use [`numpy.take`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.take.html):

```
data = np.array([0, 1, 0, 1, 1, 2, 1, 3])    
out = np.empty(data.shape, dtype=int)
rep = np.array([1,3,5,7])
np.take(rep, data, out=out)
```

Note that `numpy.take` **is not** as powerful as general advanced indexing.

Comment: Thanks! I was looking at `numpy.put`. Didn't realize `numpy.take` can do this.

Comment: @rxu What does `np.take` do for you that  standard indexing does not help with?

Comment: @cᴏʟᴅsᴘᴇᴇᴅ In tight loops, memory allocation is slow especially for very large arrays. Sometimes there isn't even enough memory for intermediates. I want to avoid the memory allocation for intermediates.

Comment: @rxu: That's C++ thinking. Memory allocation is actually pretty minor relative to other forms of overhead in Python. Other memory-related considerations, like running out of cache or outright running out of memory, can be problems, but usually, the most important thing is to make sure your tight loops aren't written in interpreted Python.

Comment: I had to work with sparse bit-arrays in c++ to use less memory. Don't ask me why ...

Answer (score 1):

Some exploratory timings:

simple indexed return:

```
In [286]: timeit out = rep[data]
357 ns ± 9.39 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Filling in an existing array - slower

```
In [287]: %%timeit out=np.empty(data.shape,data.dtype)
     ...: out[:] = rep[data]

1.15 µs ± 4.86 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1000000 loops each)
```

Using `take` to fill the array, even slower:

```
In [288]: %%timeit out=np.empty(data.shape,data.dtype)
     ...: np.take(rep, data, out=out)
5.94 µs ± 137 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100000 loops each)
```

I think the `out[:] = rep[data]` gets converted, by the interpreter into:

```
out.__setitem__(slice(None), rep.__getitem__(data))
```

We avoid buffering only if there's a compiled version of:

```
for i in range(...):
    out[i] = rep[data[i]]
```

I think that could be written with `nditer`, but that's only useful as a step toward writing a Cython version.

```
In [324]: out=np.zeros(data.shape, data.dtype)
In [325]: it = np.nditer([data, out], op_flags=[['readonly'],['readwrite']])
In [326]: for x,y in it:
     ...:     y[...]=rep[x]
     ...:     
In [327]: out
Out[327]: array([1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 5, 3, 7])
```

Comment: how big is the array? Does the benchmark recreates the out array in every loop?

Comment: I'm using your example.

Comment: If it runs `out=np.empty(data.shape,data.dtype)` in every cycle, then no point to preallocate array because it creates a new array in every cycle of the loop. I was thinking about moving that line out of the loop.

Comment: The `out=np....` is in the first line of the `%%timeit cell`, so it's outside the timing loop.  It's part of the setup.  Using a global `out` has the time.

Comment: My bad. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply index the original array:

```
>>> rep[data]
array([1, 3, 1, 3, 3, 5, 3, 7])
```